# How do I resolve an error when booting, "Couldn't find device with UUID...."

Tags: linux, rhel, boot, lvm

I have a RHEL 6 system, running on a VMWare machine. The admin of the VM server added a second RAID volume to the server, which my RHEL system does not use. Now, when I boot the RHEL system, I get a kernel fault.

If reboot without the graphical boot screen, I see these errors:

```
dracut Warning: LVM vg_mdxinfalf02/lv_swap not found
```

I'm not sure if this is tied to the added RAID volume or if the reboot somehow caused the issue.

How do I resolve this?

I ran the lvm command and when I do `pvscan`, I see:

```
Couldn't find device with uuid a30bfw-...
PV /dev/sda2       VG vg_mdxinfalf02   lvm2 [19.51 GiB / 0    free]
PV unknown device  VG vg_mdxinfalf02   lvm2 [80.00 GiB / 0    free]
```

`fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_mdxinfalf02-lv_root / ext4 defaults 1 1
UUID=48075904-965f-4aad-8cad-369469dcf0f2 /boot ext4 defaults 1 2
/dev/vg_mdxinfalf02/lv_data /var/jenkins ext3 defaults 0 0
tempfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs defaults 0 0
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
```

`blkid`:

```
dracut:/# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="48075904-965f-4aad-8cad-369649dcf0f2" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda2: UUID="LJ9wLe-cZZQ-TO8R-tRXl-lJK4-NWoI-mLYfyC" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/vg_mdxinfalf02-lv_root: UUID="50f12dee-1cd8-4a1f-a110-87f246b01cfa" TYPE="ext4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, one of your VM disks is missing. From your configuration, you seem to have:

- `sda`: 20 GB disk, part1 = `/boot`, part2 = LVM PV #1
- `sdb` (missing, name guessed): 80 GB disk, LVM PV #2

Your root partition `lv_root` is a LVM logical volume located on physical volume `sda2`. This explains why you are able to boot.

At least two other LVM logical volumes are missing: `lv_swap` and `lv_data` (`/var/jenkins`). Both are probably located on the missing physical volume #2.

You must ask your sysadmin to check the configuration of your VM on the VmWare host.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with taking a look at the setup of your system, specifically the contents of the file, `/etc/fstab`. In there it will show you what partitions are being mounted and how they're being mounted.

It's likely the case that with the addition of this new device that it's throwing the device handles off slightly, causing your system not to be able to access its swap space.

#### Example

```
$ more /etc/fstab 

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Fri Mar 14 15:20:04 2014
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/vg_catbus-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=617355d9-7864-4a70-b4b0-8bb5acd54477 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_catbus-lv_home /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_catbus-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
```

So my swap on this particular system is coming from a LV (Logical Volume) within an LVM, specifically `/dev/mapper/vg_catbus-lv_swap`. Your situation will likely be similar with your swap coming from the device, `vg_mdxinfalf02/lv_swap`.

So something is awry with your LVM device not getting setup correctly, would be my initial suspicion.

Comment: How do I access fstab?  I tried adding rdshell to my kernel command line and am in the dracut shell.  Do I need to mount the filesystem somehow?

Comment: I ran the lvm command, and when I do pvscan, I see:

`Couldn't find device with uuid a30bfw-...`
`PV /dev/sda2       VG vg_mdxinfalf02   lvm2 [19.51 GiB / 0    free]`
`PV unknown device  VG vg_mdxinfalf02   lvm2 [80.00 GiB / 0    free]`

Comment: OK, I mounted the root filesystem.  My fstab has this line:

UUID=48075904-965f-4aad-8cad-369469dcf0f2  /boot   ext4   defaults  1  2

Do I need to change something here?

Comment: Yes.  The full file is:

/dev/mapper/vg_mdxinfalf02-lv_root / ext4 defaults 1 1
UUID=48075904-965f-4aad-8cad-369469dcf0f2 /boot ext4 defaults 1 2
/dev/vg_mdxinfalf02/lv_data /var/jenkins ext3 defaults 0 0
tempfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs defaults 0 0
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0

Comment: @genevish - can you please add this to your Q? It's difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: Sorry, updated now.

Comment: @genevish - the error msg. you're receiving looks related to the add of the RAID. It looks to me like the device label for the PV (Physical Volumes) that make up VG (vg_mdxinfalf02) got shifted when the new space was allocated.

Comment: How can I resolve this?